# How to migrate Security Roles of child Business Unit from source MS-CRM to destination MS-CRM?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I have few Business Units which are child to parent Business Unit and few roles created under child Business Units.
For example:
Two Business Units: B1 and B2
Two roles: R1 and R2
R1 is under B1 Business Unit which means it is not a part of B2 and R2 is under B1 which means R2 is not a part of B1.

I migrated Business Units from Source CRM to Destination CRM with same Guid values. Now i want to migrate roles with privileges into Destination CRM.

I tried export and import from source to destination. It created Role and all privileges are empty. Even if i create Role from C# Code privileges are empty.
Can any one help me please in migrating Security Roles with Privileges?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to create security roles at the root Business Unit (BU) level.  When doing this, you can simply migrate the security role via solutions.  *In most instances*, you can set up the security role such that it does apply to all BUs correctly without having to create it in only certain BUs and not others.
All you have to do is to recreate the security role at the root level and this issue should fix itself.